# Startup Disk Creator not letting me create a startup disk?

Tags: 12.04, startup, usb-drive, disk

I'm trying to make a home server, and apparently, the type of server OS I'm wanting to run it on only work's with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I downloaded the .iso and I have my WD Pen Drive (500GB) plugged in, and when I try to create a startup disk, it won't let me create the disk. There's a screenshot below.

[image: See how "Make a startup Disk" is gray?]

Answer (score 3):

I found out that I had to erase and format the disk first, the issue has been solved